# Creating an OS X search filter panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, interface-builder

I attached an image of a **Mac Os X feature** and trying to replicate it.  Mainly the '**Search**' feature of **Mac Os X**.

*In particular how you can narrow down search results by pressing the (**+**) button to add more criteria?*

Using **XCode** & **Interface Builder**, what is the best way to go about replicating how this works?

**My Proposed Plan:**

1. Create `NSTableView` (View Based Table) with '**2 columns**'.  One to contain the content, and one for the (**+**) and (**-**) buttons.  Header will be removed and scrollBars removed on the scrollView.
2. Create `NSTableViewCell` & `SubClass` it to gain access to it's controls with **IBOutlets** & **IBActions**.  Put this in column '**1**'.
3. Populate the **subclassed NSTableViewCell** with a **PopUpControl** and corresponding other elements.
4. Populate column '**2**' with buttons for (**+**) & (**-**), and subclass that column `NSTableViewCell` as well to gain access to **IBOutlets** & **IBActions** for the controls.

This is my starting point, I will try and **upload** or **edit** this soon with a sample project I am working on. Any help is appreciated!

Looking for your thoughts and opinions and any help in this regard.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, why not use [NSPredicateEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html).

This is a control that is built into Cocoa since OS X 10.5 and is designed to do just this.

Comment: Just wanted to post that +1 ;) [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PhotoSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003994) is some source code that should help.

Comment: I tried to check out the source code but I get the following error (Code Sign error: The identity 'Mac Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains), any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I figured it out, you click on the project and turn off the 'code signing' option to compile.

Comment: Awesome, NSPredicateEditor is exactly what I was looking for! Didn't even know about that class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 2-column table view - use 1-column view-based ones instead, and in the views use constraints and/or manual layout code to place the buttons.

Also, the container should be a split view housing 2 table views and the split is managed by code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an NSTableView at all here. NSTableView is a powerful class. Lots of things it does -- managing selections, highlighting selected cells, scrolling, recycling views that have scrolled off the screen -- aren't useful in this context, and some will actually get in your way.  The only real "table-ness" you're using is layout, and you can get tabular layout easily in a number of ways.

Maxthon Chan is right, though, is thinking you want a fairly elaborate view-controller pair that will handle each row of the table.  This pair of classes abstracts out one clause of the search query and presents a simple interface to the parent controller, a controller that assembles the whole query ready to run. For each line, you'll need

```
 - (MyQueryClause*) getQuery;
```

while the parent controller keeps track of all the active clauses and handles the Add/Delete buttons:

```
 - (IBAction) addClause: (id) sender;
 - (IBAction) removeClause: (id) sender;
```